# How do I debug HikariCP losing connections?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, hikaricp

I use HikariCP with Play 2.6.10. The application will run fine for days, and then all of our connections will leak. I have `leakDetectionThreshold` turned on, so we get stack traces for leaked connections like:

```
2018-01-24 06:29:00,857 - [WARN] - from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask in 
HikariPool-2 housekeeper 
Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@65cd084 on thread pool-1-thread-1, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.jav
a:85)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:152)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:148)
        at models.summaries.ActionSummary$.listByStripe(ActionSummary.scala:137)
```

I only use the connections through Play's `withConnection`, so they should be returned to the pool automatically. A thread dump, when the application is in a broken state, shows that all threads inside of a `withConnection` block are stuck on...

```
"application-akka.mysql-context-122" #32142 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fca7812a
000 nid=0x28e6 waiting on condition [0x00007fca7541c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for   (a java.util.concurrent.Sync
hronousQueue$TransferQueue)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215
)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.awaitFulfill(Sync
hronousQueue.java:764)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.transfer(Synchron
ousQueue.java:695)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.borrow(ConcurrentBag.java:157)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:165)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:147)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:85)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:152)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:148)
```

...waiting for a connection to be available, which should mean that none are currently holding a connection. I have no idea how any connection could possible be leaked, but apparently all of them have. We see logging lines like:

```
2018-01-24 06:19:21,297 - [DEBUG] - from com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in application-akka.mysql-context-129 
HikariPool-2 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=15)
```

The only unusual thing we are doing is calling `setNetworkTimeout` on each connection we obtain, sometimes with a timeout as low as 10 seconds. This is done to ensure that queries fail fast if we lose connection to the DB.

I'm not sure what to do next debugging this. It looks like maybe a potential issue between Hikari and Play, or something broken with MySQL and `setNetworkTimeout`.

Comment: I see a "seam" in the Play code which can leak.  Databases:148 calls line 152 which calls [line:142](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/b5a88b3af2b806d519cf4d7afad704f847f4899d/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/Databases.scala#L152).  You can see that line 153 sets up a try-finally block, but the connection aquisition occurs outside of that block.  That would be fine if ``getConnection()`` actually only did that.  However, line 143 can throw *after* the connection is borrowed, but before the try-finally.  This can leak.  I suggest reporting it to Play.

Comment: Good catch @brettw. I opened a pull request with a fix at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/8198

Comment: Nice find @brettw. @wingedsubmariner, I've made a suggestion on the PR. In this case I'd say the problem is probably something else. If there was an exception being through in `getConnection` that would probably show up in a more obvious way. When the connections leak, does it happen all at once or is it a gradual thing?